# Trouble Understanding general Quartic soulution from the Wiki what is $\Delta_1^2$ and $\Delta_0^3$

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to implement the general quartic solution for use in a ray tracer, but I'm having some trouble. The solvers I've found do cause some strange false negatives leaving holes in the tori I'm testing with.

Most implementations use the depressed quartic solutions, I don't understand the math involved and can't figure out why I'm having false non-intersections (link to layman explanation would be great).  So I'm trying to implement the general solution at [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).  I got the stuff up until the special cases implemented, but at that point I have an issue.

When there are 4 unique roots the term they've called Q becomes non-real, and S must be calculated with the special case trig-based equations.  The problem is the angle is calculated as $\arccos{\frac{\Delta_1}{2\sqrt{\Delta_0^3}}}$ but I cannot find where $\Delta_0^3$ is defined. It does not seem to appear anywhere else in the entire wikipedia entry. Am I missing it or does anyone know what it should be?

Comment: $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_1$ are defined towards the end of the sub-section to which you've linked, and right above the subsection dealing with Special Cases.

Comment: So your saying the superscript on those is in fact a power and not a denotation of a separate entity? I would have expected the super script number to have a separation in that case. ie. ${\Delta_0}^3$ instead of $\Delta_0^3$

Comment: @Lucian After implementing them as such, you are quite correct, I was misunderstanding the notation. Thank you, if your comment was an answer I would gladly accept it if you would like to write one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_1$ are defined towards the end of the subsection to which you've linked, and right above the subsection dealing with Special Cases. The $3$ is an exponent, not a superscript index.